# Trying to remove www from custom URL for a Heroku app

Tags: heroku, sinatra

I purchased a domain from namecheap.com and have pointed it to my Heroku app successfully:

www.markrandhawa.com

I'm now trying to prevent the www part from showing in the URL but having difficulty doing so. I've looked at the Heroku doc for adding custom domains and added the following code, but this hasn't worked:

```
heroku domains:add markrandhawa.com
```

In my namecheap account, I tried changing the '@' in 'All Host Records' to URL Frame but this didn't work either. When going into page source of markrandhawa.com, it said:

```
<frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://www.markrandhawa.com/" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.</h2><br><br>
<center>Click <a href="http://www.markrandhawa.com/" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
</noframes>
```

I'm using Chrome.

However, when using a proxy, it seems as though my site is loading using mark.randhawa.com (without the www) as shown in the following link:

http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://markrandhawa.com

I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: What you can do is URL forwding from your root domain to www.markrandhawa.com. Have a look at this Namecheap knowledgebase article - [How do I set up URL forwarding for a domain](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-set-up-url-forwarding-for-a-domain).

Answer (score 2):

Heroku has very limited support for hosting root domains. Your DNS provider must be able to set `ALIAS` records, which is something most services do not provide. If Namecheap does not provide this service, hosting your root domain on Heroku is not possible.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain for more information on configuring `ALIAS` records, or alternatively setting up a redirect proxy.